# Mutual gains from trade: did Smith come up with the idea or did Menger?

Tags: history-economic-thought, austrian, adam-smith

Here's the [EconLib page](https://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/bios/Menger.html) for reference. In the third paragraph, it says

> Menger used his “subjective theory of value” to arrive at one of the
> most powerful insights in economics: both sides gain from exchange.
> People will exchange something they value less for something they
> value more. Because both trading partners do this, both gain.

I thought the idea of mutual gains from trade come from Adam Smith! Was I wrong all along?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of gains from trade did already existed in Smith. Blinder mentions that in the [EconLib](https://www.econlib.org/library/Enc/FreeTrade.html) as well. You can also directly read it in the Wealth of Nations by Smith:

> It is the maxim of every prudent master of a family, never to attempt to make at home what it will cost him more to make than to buy.. . . If a foreign country can supply us with a commodity cheaper than we ourselves can make it, better buy it of them with some part of the produce of our own industry, employed in a way in which we have some advantage.

Either the author made a mistake or author refers to the fact that Menger provided rigorous positive explanation for the phenomenon.